# How can i calculate the percentage of a number greater or equal to a certain number from a file

Tags: python, math, percentage

I have a CSV file separated by commas. I need to read the file, determine which lines contain a number that needs to be higher than a given number (say 711), and calculate the percentage of those numbers that fit the criteria.

My code so far is as follows:

```
myfile = open('3517315a.csv','r')

myfilecount = 0

linecount = 0

firstline = True

for line in myfile:
    if firstline:
        firstline = False
        continue
fields = line.split(',')

    linecount += 1
    count = int(fields[0])
    colour = str(fields[1])
    channels = int(fields[2])
    code = str(fields[3])
    correct = str(fields[4])
    reading = float(fields[5])

print( 'percentage of numbers greater than or equal to 711 is %d:')
```

I do not know how I can set the condition and then calculate the percentage.

Comment: Copy paste your code, don't screenshot. And further describe your problem please

Comment: Make sure all your code is formatted using the Code tool '{}' when creating your question. So the code displays correctly. Also make sure write something in your question. Don't just rely on the Question itself.

Comment: Tried to explain what is the purpose of the code, and what the question could be. I am assuming is someone who is just starting to code, and is using Python to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are interested in counting only the first field (count), then the code can be something like:

```
MAGIC_NUMBER = 711

counter = 0
myfile = open('3517315a.csv', 'r')

myfile.readline()  # Skip the first line

for i, line in enumerate(myfile, 1):
    count = int(line.split(',')[0])

    if count >= MAGIC_NUMBER:
        counter += 1

percentage = float(counter) / i * 100
print('%3.2f%% of numbers is >= %d' % (percentage, MAGIC_NUMBER))
```

You can use `enumerate` to get automatically a sequence of numbers, in this case, from reading each `line` from `myfile`, starting from 1.

Because we are only interested in the first field, and we know the `split` method returns a list, we only take the first element (index 0). We convert such number to a number (`int`).

Then you need to count those numbers according to the given condition.

Once we processed the file, `i` holds the last number of lines read. So we can compute the percentage. Notice the use of `float` in one of the numbers. That is to tell the operator `/` we want a `float` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an awk command:-

```
cat 3517315a.csv | awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{count=0;total=0;}{total++;if($1>=711)count++;}END{print 100*count/total}'
```

Explanation:-

`awk -F ','` - specifies the field seperator

`BEGIN{count=0;total=0;}` - initializes the variables first time.

`{total++;if($1>=711)count++;}` - executes for every line in the file. total is incremented for each line, count is incremented for only those >= 711.

`END{print 100*count/total}` - executes after all lines are parsed. `Percentage=count*100/total`

Comment: can you please explain further?

Comment: Alan, I've added an explanation.